# How to enable debug mode on a Sony Bravia KDL-50W508B?

Tags: sony, google-tv

How to enable debug mode on a Sony Bravia KDL-50W508B? The 
[sony website](https://developer.sony.com/develop/tvs/android-tv/get-started/) suggests:

> 1. On your target device, show Developer options by clicking on About > Build several times.
>      Click DPAD_CENTER multiple times.

I could not find any build information under

Home > Help > Customer Support > System Information.

Answer (score 3):

To enable debug mode first:

Settings -> TV -> About.

Scroll down to and click on Build until a dialog appears with the message "You are now a developer" appears.

Then to Enable Debugging

Settings -> System Preferences row -> Developer options -> Debugging -> ADB Debugging -> On.